# Triggering actions on mouseover and mouseleave events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My Button is on top and I wish to achieve the following:

1. Show a modal on `mouseover` event of a `button`.
2. Hide that modal on the `mouseleave` event of a modal.
3. Leaving that button from top, left or right side also hides that
   modal

```js
$(".modal-content1").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  modal.style.display = "none";
});
var modal = document.getElementById('aaa');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function fun() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
$(function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target !== modal) {

  } else if (event.target !== modal && event.target !== btn) {
    //alert("ggg");
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }


}
```

```css
.modal-content1 {
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 10px;" onmouseover="fun()"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span>  Services</button>

<div class="modal-content1" id="aaa">
  <h1> ABCDH</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a JSFIDDLE from your code

**I think this is the solution:**

css

```
.modal-content1 {
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

html

```
<button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 10px;" onmouseover=""><span class="fa fa-bars"></span>  Services</button>

 <div class="modal-content1" id="aaa">
      <h1>  ABCDH</h1>
    </div>
```

js / jquery

```
//hide modal
$('#aaa').hide();

$('#myBtn').mouseover(function(){
    $('#aaa').show();
});

$('#myBtn').mouseleave(function(event){
    //mouseleave button downwards
  if(!(event.pageY > 28 && event.pageY < 32))
  {
        $('#aaa').hide();
  }
});

$('#aaa').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#aaa').hide();
});
```

Link to jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yamLxqnm/
If you have any questions, just let me know :)

Comment: I tried your code but actualy sir in my case when I go down from that button it is hiding that modal. Do I required to change the values of event.PageY and event.PageX??

Comment: Hi, you need to change the values based on your live code. You can easily test this by console logging the event.pageY;

Comment: Hello Sir . Its is working. I changed the value of event.pageY.  I am very thankful to you for your help. Since 5-6 days i was struglling to solve this problem. Thnk U

Comment: You could also try to delete: && event.pageY < 32 and set the event.pageY to the correct value;

Comment: oh i am sorry sir. Actually I dont know process for voting. Coz i m new to this site. Can u plz tell me how to vote for your answer?

Comment: hello sir, Can u plz help me. I have 1 query about same question relating to responsive format. If u dont have any problem then I can ask my query.

Comment: Yes, whats the problem ? :)

Comment: mouse over event does not works in responsive mode. Means if i will work this code in mobile view using F12 then mouse over event doesnot work. So I need to activate click event of button using jquery.

Comment: Actually I want 2 things in responsive mode ..... 1- showing modal on click event of a button  2 - Hiding modal on windows click event excepting modal. For this I have written following code click event of button is working but doesnot showing modal Following is my code -